# EWS emails have base64 img tags encoded

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

**Background context:**

I'm using EWS Managed API 2.0 to connect to customer Outlook mailbox and process their emails into my application. I do not have control over what kind of emails the customers send, however part of the processing is maintaining the attachments and embedded images that are being sent.

**My problem:**

One of the users has sent an HTML type email with a base64 image as part of his signature. The Exchange Api gets the body of the email HTML encoded and part of the body, base64 images are encoded as well (converted the '+' sign to '& #43;'), which now breaks my application.

**Question:** Is there a way to retrieve the email body without having the base64 images encoded? As a workaround, right now I'm doing a string replace of '& #43;' to '+'.

This is part of the code I'm using to get the email body; The Assembly I'm using:  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices Version=15.0.0.0

```
var service = new ExchangeService(Exchange2010_SP2);
// rest of creating the service

var singleEmailView = new ItemView(1);
SearchFilter unreadEmailsFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
var emailResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, unreadEmailsFilter, singleEmailView);

if (emailResults.Items.Any())
    {
        var firstItem = emailResults.Items.First();
        var email = firstItem as EmailMessage;
        email.Load();

        var propertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.MimeContent, EmailMessageSchema.IsRead);
        service.LoadPropertiesForItems(new List<Item> { firstItem }, propertySet);

        var  body = firstItem.Body;
    }
```

Doing email.Body or firstItem.Body retrives the same HTML.

This is an example of an email with encoded base64 image - see '& #43;' in img src:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<b>HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII <b><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJosM//AwO/AwHVYZ/z595kzAP/s7P&#43;goOXMv8&#43;fhw/v739/f&#43;8PD98fH/8mJl&#43;fn/9ZWb8/PzWlwv///6wWGbImAPgTEMImIN9gUFCEm/gDALULDN8PAD6atYdCTX9gUNKlj8wZAKUsAOzZz&#43;UMAOsJAP/Z2ccMDA8PD/95eX5NWvsJCOVNQPtfX/8zM8&#43;QePLl38MGBr8JCP&#43;zs9myn/8GBqwpAP/GxgwJCPny78lzYLgjAJ8vAP9fX/&#43;MjMUcAN8zM/9wcM8ZGcATEL&#43;QePdZWf/29uc/P9cmJu9MTDImIN&#43;/r7&#43;/vz8/P8VNQGNugV8AAF9fX8swMNgTAFlDOICAgPNSUnNWSMQ5MBAQEJE3QPIGAM9AQMqGcG9vb6MhJsEdGM8vLx8fH98AANIWAMuQeL8fABkTEPPQ0OM5OSYdGFl5jo&#43;Pj/&#43;pqcsTE78wMFNGQLYmID4dGPvd3UBAQJmTkP&#43;8vH9QUK&#43;vr8ZWSHpzcJMmILdwcLOGcHRQUHxwcK9PT9DQ0O/v70w5MLypoG8wKOuwsP/g4P/Q0IcwKEswKMl8aJ9fX2xjdOtGRs/Pz&#43;Dg4GImIP8gIH0sKEAwKKmTiKZ8aB/f39Wsl&#43;LFt8dgUE9PT5x5aHBwcP&#43;AgP&#43;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&#43;euTeJm1Ki7A73qNWtFiF&#43;/gA95Gly2CJLDhwEHMOUAAuOpLYDEgBxZ4GRTlC1fDnpkM&#43;fOqD6DDj1aZpITp0dtGCDhr&#43;fVuCu3zlg49ijaokTZTo27uG7Gjn2P&#43;hI8&#43;PDPERoUB318bWbfAJ5sUNFcuGRTYUqV/3ogfXp1rWlMc6awJjiAAd2fm4ogXjz56aypOoIde4OE5u/F9x199dlXnnGiHZWEYbGpsAEA3QXYnHwEFliKAgswgJ8LPeiUXGwedCAKABACCN&#43;EA1pYIIYaFlcDhytd51sGAJbo3onOpajiihlO92KHGaUXGwWjUBChjSPiWJuOO/LYIm4v1tXfE6J4gCSJEZ7YgRYUNrkji9P55sF/ogxw5ZkSqIDaZBV6aSGYq/lGZplndkckZ98xoICbTcIJGQAZcNmdmUc210hs35nCyJ58fgmIKX5RQGOZowxaZwYA&#43;JaoKQwswGijBV4C6SiTUmpphMspJx9unX4KaimjDv9aaXOEBteBqmuuxgEHoLX6Kqx&#43;yXqqBANsgCtit4FWQAEkrNbpq7HSOmtwag5w57GrmlJBASEU18ADjUYb3ADTinIttsgSB1oJFfA63bduimuqKB1keqwUhoCSK374wbujvOSu4QG6UvxBRydcpKsav&#43;&#43;Ca6G8A6Pr1x2kVMyHwsVxUALDq/krnrhPSOzXG1lUTIoffqGR7Goi2MAxbv6O2kEG56I7CSlRsEFKFVyovDJoIRTg7sugNRDGqCJzJgcKE0ywc0ELm6KBCCJo8DIPFeCWNGcyqNFE06ToAfV0HBRgxsvLThHn1oddQMrXj5DyAQgjEHSAJMWZwS3HPxT/QMbabI/iBCliMLEJKX2EEkomBAUCxRi42VDADxyTYDVogV&#43;wSChqmKxEKCDAYFDFj4OmwbY7bDGdBhtrnTQYOigeChUmc1K3QTnAUfEgGFgAWt88hKA6aCRIXhxnQ1yg3BCayK44EWdkUQcBByEQChFXfCB776aQsG0BIlQgQgE8qO26X1h8cEUep8ngRBnOy74E9QgRgEAC8SvOfQkh7FDBDmS43PmGoIiKUUEGkMEC/PJHgxw0xH74yx/3XnaYRJgMB8obxQW6kL9QYEJ0FIFgByfIL7/IQAlvQwEpnAC7DtLNJCKUoO/w45c44GwCXiAFB/OXAATQryUxdN4LfFiwgjCNYg&#43;kYMIEFkCKDs6PKAIJouyGWMS1FSKJOMRB/BoIxYJIUXFUxNwoIkEKPAgCBZSQHQ1A2EWDfDEUVLyADj5AChSIQW6gu10bE/JG2VnCZGfo4R4d0sdQoBAHhPjhIB94v/wRoRKQWGRHgrhGSQJxCS&#43;0pCZbEhAAOw==">
</b></b>
</body>
</html>
```